Simulate an LFU cache
I am trying to simulate a LFU cache. The task is simple; with any new request I want the cache to print out the key of the request and whether it was a HIT or a MISS. E.g.10 MISS 10 HIT 20 MISS 10 HIT  and so on. Preferably, I would also like to store the output in a list.
My code so far is only this:
from cachetools import cached,LFUCache
@cached(cache=LFUCache(maxsize=3),info=True)
def channel(chnum:int):
    print(f"{chnum} MISSED")
    return None

This code prints out if chnum is not in the cache but I still need the HIT situations. For this I may need I think  to override the __getitem__() method in a subclass but I don't know how to do.
This is an example overriding the method popitem() in a subclass MyCache:
class MyCache(LFUCache):
    def popitem(self):
        key, value = super().popitem()
        print('CHannel "%s" evicted with value "%s"' % (key, value))
        return key, value 

@cached(cache=MyCache( maxsize=2))
def channel(chnum:int):
        print(f"{chnum} MISSED")
        return None

I need something similar, a subclass for the __getitem_() method that out puts the key of the request and also whether it is a miss or a hit.
Finally, I would like to store the whole output in a list.

I'd code it from scratch so that we'd have control over any changes that we are interested in.
We can also count the number of cache hits:

from collections import defaultdict


class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, val):
        self.key, self.val = key, val
        self.prev = self.next = None
        self.freq = 1


class DLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sentinel = Node(None, None)
        self.sentinel.next = self.sentinel.prev = self.sentinel
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def append(self, node):
        node.next, node.prev = self.sentinel.next, self.sentinel
        node.next.prev = node
        self.sentinel.next = node
        self.size += 1

    def popitem(self, node=None):
        if self.size == 0:
            return
        if not node:
            node = self.sentinel.prev
        node.prev.next = node.next
        node.next.prev = node.prev
        self.size -= 1
        return node


class LFU:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.size, self.capacity = 0, capacity
        self.node = {}
        self.freq = defaultdict(DLL)
        self.minf = 0
        self.hit_count = 0
        self.miss_count = 0

    def __update(self, node):
        f = node.freq
        self.freq[f].popitem(node)
        if self.minf == f and not self.freq[f]:
            self.minf += 1
        node.freq += 1
        f = node.freq
        self.freq[f].append(node)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.node:
            self.miss_count += 1
            return "MISS"
        self.hit_count += 1
        node = self.node[key]
        self.__update(node)
        return node.val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if self.capacity == 0:
            return

        if key in self.node:
            self.hit_count += 1
            print("HIT")
            node = self.node[key]
            self.__update(node)
            node.val = val
        else:
            self.miss_count += 1
            print("MISS")
            if self.size == self.capacity:
                node = self.freq[self.minf].popitem()
                del self.node[node.key]
                self.size -= 1
            node = Node(key, val)
            self.node[key] = node
            self.freq[1].append(node)
            self.minf = 1
            self.size += 1


cache = LFU(3)
cache.__setitem__("apple", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("orange", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("cherry", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__setitem__("banana", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")


Prints
MISS
MISS
MISS
HIT count: 6
MISS count: 6
MISS
HIT count: 7
MISS count: 7
HIT count: 8
MISS count: 7

Note:

We are using a doubly linked list here.


Yeah, here is an example of override __getitem__ and __setitem__. In fact, I suggest logging hit and miss events in these two functions instead of your channel function.
from cachetools import cached, LFUCache

class MyCache(LFUCache):
    def __init__(self, maxsize, getsizeof=None):
        super().__init__(maxsize, getsizeof)
        # Add a list for records events
        self.__logs = []

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        # ValueError will be raised when cache missed
        print(f'{key} HIT')
        self.__logs.append((key, "HIT"))
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value) -> None:
        print(f'{key} MISSED')
        self.__logs.append((key, "MISSED"))
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def popitem(self):
        key, value = super().popitem()
        print('CHannel "%s" evicted with value "%s"' % (key, value))
        return key, value 

    def pop(self, key):
        # override `pop` to avoid extra `__getitem__` call leading to redundant HIT record
        value = LFUCache.__getitem__(self, key)
        del self[key]
        return value    

    def get_logs(self):
        return self.__logs

To visit the log instead of employing any global variable, we can make an instance of MyCache to refer it later.
_channel_cache = MyCache(maxsize=3)

@cached(cache=_channel_cache,info=True)
def channel(chnum: int):
    # Do some thing here
    return chnum * 10

Then Let's verify the implementation:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel(1)
    channel(2)
    channel(3)
    channel(1)
    channel(4)
    print(_channel_cache.get_logs())

From the codes below, we can get output as
(1,) MISSED
(2,) MISSED
(3,) MISSED
(1,) HIT
(4,) MISSED
CHannel "(2,)" evicted with value "20"
[((1,), 'MISSED'), ((2,), 'MISSED'), ((3,), 'MISSED'), ((1,), 'HIT'), ((4,), 'MISSED')]

Note: the key is a tuple as it is actually the parameter list of the function.

Very clear explanation and perfect solution. Works fine. Thank you.

You can instrument the cache yourself:
from cachetools import cached, LFUCache

class MyCache(LFUCache):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hminfo = []

    def __getitem__(self, key, **kwargs):
        self.hminfo.append((key, 'HIT' if key in self else 'MISS'))
        return super().__getitem__(key, **kwargs)

Example usage:
mycache = MyCache(maxsize=3)
@cached(cache=mycache, info=True)
def channel(x, y):
    return x * y

>>> channel(1, 2)
2

>>> channel(1, 2)
2

>>> channel(3, 5)
15

>>> mycache.hminfo
[((1, 2), 'MISS'), ((1, 2), 'HIT'), ((3, 15), 'MISS')]

